# Vue 3: configure globale template for all pages in MPA (Multi Page App) configuration

Tags: javascript, templates, vuejs3

I am new to Vue. I am using Vue with the MPA configuration. I want to have one template for all files. This is my configuration in vue.config.js:

```
pages: {
    'index': {
        entry: vueWorkDirPath + '/page/public/home/home.js'
    },
    'test': {
        entry: vueWorkDirPath + '/page/public/test/test.js'
    }
}
```

I then add this to my chainWebpack config in vue.config.js:

```
chainWebpack: config => {
     config
        .plugin('html')
        .tap(args => {
            args[0].template = vueWorkDirPath + '/template/default.html'
            return args
        })
}
```

But then I get this error:

> Cannot call .tap() on a plugin that has not yet been defined. Call plugin('html').use(<Plugin>) first

So, when I remove the 'html' plugin config, and adapt my pages config like this it works flawlessly:

```
pages: {
    'index': {
        entry: vueWorkDirPath + '/page/public/home/home.js',
        template: vueWorkDirPath + '/template/default.html'
    },
    'test': {
        entry: vueWorkDirPath + '/page/public/test/test.js',
        template: vueWorkDirPath + '/template/default.html'
    }
}
```

Like this, it loads for every file the same template. But it seems a bit cumbersome for me, so I though to just load one template for all the files. Hence, the configuration I found with the 'html' plugin. When using this plugin for a SPA with only one index.html file for instance, it works then. It seems that Vue uses different plugins for an MPA according to this website:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1729

Therefore, my question is: what is the best way to have only one entry of a global template in an MPA? I guess I could fix it by adding the 'html' plugin described in the link above for an MPA, but I am too new and don't know how to do it. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Actually the answer is right there on the same page, specifically [this comment](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1729#issuecomment-402217659) :-).

Comment: @YomS. it doesn't explain how to configure a global template for all pages. My attempt of using the plugin might be wrong... It only explains why the error is thrown. It doesn't says how to fix the error. For instance, if it is possible to install the html plugin per page... But then again, if that attempt is wrong, how do I configure a global page template? ;-)

Comment: I think it does explain how to fix the error to some extent though. Did you run `vue inspect --plugins` and see the output? The key focus is in the plugin ids that are prefixed with `html-`.

Comment: If you're okay with using glob patterns for the entry points, there's a beta [plugin](https://github.com/clm-a/multipage-html-webpack-plugin) that might help, as it allows you to specify a "common" layout/template for the pages.